# Persist faded in field

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Rails 4.2.

I have a form, where next dropdown is dependent on the previous selection.

The following works (we have a mapping between rails controllers and js files):

```
(function(App, $, undefined) {
  'use strict';

  App.AdminReports = function() { # controller name

    this.create = function(e) {
      $('#quarter').css('display', 'none');
      $('#kind_vo').change(function(){
        if($('#kind_vo :selected').text() == 'Cele firm' || $('#kind_vo :selected').text() == 'Cele lokalizacji'){
          $('#quarter').fadeIn('fast');
        }
      });
    };
  };
})(window.App = window.App || {}, jQuery);
```

But if this faded in field does not pass a rails validation (n my case it is `validates :quarter, presence: true`) it disappears again. Is there a way to persist the field longer? I suppose it is happening because of reloading the page on the backend validation fail.

How should I proceed?

May be there is an easy way to persist the faded in field until the controller changes or something like this..

Comment: Check the value of dropdown 1 at page load and show the second dropdown. Or check the value in your view and add a `.hidden` class to the second dropdown if it the first does not have the correct value.

Comment: Basically if you are using turbolinks you have to realize that it empties the body tag and appends the new content. So the input element after validation is not the same DOM element as before. So you have to either recreate the state or set it from the view.

Comment: @max Thanks a lot man for your input! Appreciate it, really!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would approach the problem:

#### 1. Add a hidden CSS class:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

#### 2. Create a helper for outputting the form rows.

```
module FormRowHelper
  # A thin wrapper around content_tag to produce an input row.
  # @param [Symbol|String] tag_name
  # @param [Hash] kwargs - hash of options passed to content_tag
  #   @option [Boolean] show - adds a hidden class if false
  # @yield block to content_tag
  # @return [String]
  def input_row(tag_name = :div, show: true, **kwargs, &block)
    classes = kwargs[:class].try(:split) || ['row']
    classes << ['hidden'] unless show
    options = kwargs.except(:class).merge(
      class: classes.join(' ')
    )
    content_tag(tag_name, options) do
      yield if block_given?
    end
  end
end
```

#### 3. Use the helper to show/hide the inputs for B depending on the state of A.

```
<%= form_for(@model) do |f| %>

  <div class="row">
    <%= f.select :a do %>
      <%= options_for_select(
        ['Cele firm','Cele lokalizacji', 'Foo', 'Bar']
        )
      %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <%= input_row(
    show: ['Cele firm', 'Cele lokalizacji'].include?(@model.a), 
    id: 'kind_vo') do %>
    <%= f.select :b do %>
      <%= options_for_select([
        ['Lisbon', 1, { 'data-size' => '2.8 million' }],
        ['Madrid', 2, { 'data-size' => '3.2 million' }]
        ])
      %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'll try it soon, thanks a bunch! Looks like a great approach